Running a cronjob that requires setting of several environment variables in particular directory
I need to setup Cron Job to run regressions for which I usually follow below steps in terminal:
cd path/to/regression_dir/
source setup.csh
perl "regression_script.pl"

The setup.csh files contains environment variables that will be needed to run the perl script. And cd command is necessary since setup.csh checkouts particular git branches, etc.
I tried creating another shell script like so:
#!/bin/csh
cd path/to/regression_dir/
source setup.csh
perl "regression_script.pl"

And then to setup the Cron Job like so via crontab -e:
SHELL=/bin/csh
0 0 * * 5 /path/to/shell_script/ > ~/log.txt

However, this isn't working. Neither did I receive any error message in the file I have redirected the Cron Job output (log.txt)
How can I achieve this?

Maybe it is a typo in the question, but your cd is not an absolute directory (does it on cronjob: better to be explicit, you never know). Also your log: you use single >, so every 5 minutes you override (and also: use full path, ~ is special ($HOME is more portable but... I would not assume system is fully setup (especially if you run in docker): be explicit on paths!)

... as written, the job is run every minute, but only on weekday #5 I think? perhaps that was not the OPs intent (at least, not while debugging)

@steeldriver It was a type, I meant 0 0 * * 5 for the scheduling. And to redirect the error stream, just > log.txt was working fine for me for other Cron jobs. However, I did try appending 2>&1 yet I didn't get any error messages

With csh, the syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr is with >& file.log

I have deleted my comment since the OP changed SHELL=/bin/bash to SHELL=/bin/csh

cron uses a shell to interpret the command line given in the crontab. By default, it's sh, but by setting the SHELL variable in the crontab like you do here, you can get a different shell.
So you can have that shell do the sourcing:
SHELL=/bin/csh
0 0 * * 5 (cd path/to/regression_dir && source setup.csh && perl regression_script.pl) >& log.txt

To run that at midnight in the morning of every Friday.
The initial working directory in cron jobs is the home directory of the user so we as long as your home dir exists and you have access to it, we don't need the ~/ in ~/log.txt and the path/to/regression_dir will be ~/path/to/regression_dir.
Note the && to separate commands so that the next command is only run if the previous one succeeded and the >& log.txt instead of > log.txt which in csh is the syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr (equivalent of the Bourne shell's > log.txt 2>&1).
When not redirected, the output and errors are sent by email to the user.
